# Flutter web textfield disappearing or taking so much time to transition between two textfields

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web, flutter-ios

I have a flutter app that is running across android,ios and web. I have different pages that contain multiple textfields for the user to fill his info and signup/login. The textfields display no problems in the apk or the .app in ios. The main problem is in web when opened from an iphone (ios) . The behavior is not consistent on all iphones but the main problem is that  either the texfields flicker/disappear or the transition from a textfield to another takes about 12 seconds. A video is attached below to show the behavior  on iphone 6 safari browser (the same happens with chrome). Other iphones show a delay between the transition from a textfield to another(tested on iphone 11)
Flutter doctor :
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 2.2.3 at D:\flutter-src\flutter
• Framework revision f4abaa0735 (5 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
• Engine revision 241c87ad80
• Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Alpha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.3.7)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.3.29424.173
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.17763.0
X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop
development with C++" workload, and include these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
- If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
C++ CMake tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.131
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 92.0.902.55

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

video link :

```
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/63854743/128207268-42c0b5ab-f871-453b-bd06-d807112920ff.mp4
```